# Shiny in RStudio RPres?

Tags: r, rstudio, rpres

I am learning `RPres` and so far I really like it. Now I would like to insert an `RShiny` App in my presentation. I read the instructions for inserting Shiny in [RMarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_embedded_shiny.html) and tried to apply a similar approach in `RPres`:

````
# A Shiny App in RPres?
========================================================

```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(shiny)
shinyAppDir(
  system.file("examples/06_tabsets", package="shiny"),
  options=list(
    width="100%", height=700
  )
)
```
````

Which then gives the error:

> Error in appshot.shiny.appobj(list(httpHandler = function (req) :
>   appshot of Shiny app objects is not yet supported.

I can't find any good documentation for RPres and Shiny.Is this even possible?
Is there a workaround, like generating something from RMarkdown that could then be inserted in RPres?

Comment: "`not yet supported`" seems pretty clear. Maybe you should make a presentation from Rmarkdown instead of using Rpres. It seems to be taking most of the RStudio developer's attention.

Comment: SO is not the right place for feature requests, and requests for the answering audience doing searches to find other packages is deprecated.

Comment: My post was not meant as a feature request. I was asking about possible kludges for how to achieve what I want to do with the existing versions. I will look further into RMarkdown and IOSlides.  If SO wants to close this thread, I am fine with that.

Answer (score 1):

The .Rpres format does not support Shiny, but you can make something very similar that does using R Markdown. .Rpres is built on reveal.js. You can install reveal.js in such a way that you can use it in R Markdown documents. Instructions here:

http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/revealjs_presentation_format.html

Once you've converted your presentation to R Markdown (should be very little work other than adding the YAML header as described above and tweaking headings) you can use Shiny apps in your presentation as in the tutorial you linked.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be support for the shiny runtime while using reveal js. The only presentation that currently supports the shiny runtime is ioslides_presentation. Hopefully that changes in the future!